# $(...).modal is not a function when using jQuery Modal plugin

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using [this](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#installation) jQuery Modal Plugin to show a popup on my site.

When the page loads, I want to delay the popup by 5 seconds, but is not working together with the "setTimeout" method.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 $('#ex1').modal({
    fadeDuration: 500,
    showClose: false
 );
}, 5000)
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

So whenever I use the "setTimeout" method, I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function", but it works fine without it.

Edit: I also noticed that is not working when I try to call it inside of window.onload = function() {}

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should include jquery first before the library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have included jQuery before the library.